# autogenerating ant files from template in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant

Every time I start a new Java project, I find I keep copying my build.xml file from the previous Java project. Is there a way in Eclipse I can just set up a template file, and have it substitute in project specific info (name & directory) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up Ant templates and use them for a variety of purposes.

Go to Window->Preferences->Ant->Editor->Templates, then create a new template or modify an existing one to suit your purposes.

There's a [nifty little video](https://eclipse-tutorial.dev.java.net/visual-tutorials/antcodetemplate.html) that shows you some of the options.